# Invoke implicit class in a parameterized abstract class level (Scala)

Tags: scala, implicit, parameterized

I have an issue, something like the following:

```
//project entities

abstract class AbstractEntity
class EntityA extends AbstractEntity

// implicit converters
trait Converter[V] {def convert (entity: V): V}
object Converters{

  implicit object ConvertEntityA extends Converter[EntityA]{
  def convert = ???//do something
   .....
  }
}

//Use this class to perform convert operation
object ConvertUtils{
  def an[V](entity: V)(implicit converter: Converter[V]) =      
  converter.convert(entity)
  ....
}

//utility classes
abstract class AbstractEntityUtil{
  val entityClass: Class[T] = ... gets it by reflection
  val convertedEntity = Convert an entityClass.newInstance()  
}
class EntityAUtil extends AbstractEntityUtil{
   def printIt = print(convertedEntity)

}
```

I would like to call print from EntityAUtil, which will trigger a
 conversion of ConvertEntityA, but gets the obvious error :

Error:(38, 31) could not find implicit value for parameter converter: packageName.Converter[V]
     "val entity: T =  Convert a (entityClass.newInstance())"
                               ^

I managed to get it work only when invoke convertEntity from ConvertEntityA,
can I make it work the way I want somehow?